# How can I move a dialog window in Applescript?

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I've been told that, technically, you can't move a dialog in AppleScript. Amazingly, the following code works.

I'm running a script for InDesign that creates a dialog box. Opening a new AppleScript Editor window and running this code will move the dialog box:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Adobe InDesign CS6"
        set position of window 1 to {1000, 400}
    end tell
end tell
```

The problem is: I can't figure out a way to incorporate this code directly into my original script -- it just doesn't work, no matter what I try or where I insert it into the code. I have to run it from AppleScript Editor

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialog boxes are usually blocking in the host application.  You can certainly tell System Events to move a window, but Adobe InDesign itself is busy throwing up a blocking dialog box at the time, so it can't move its own dialog box.

If you want to get clever, you can fork off a process at the correct time and with the magically correct delays to move your dialog for you.  This would be something like

```
do shell script "osascript -e 'delay 4' -e " & (quoted form of "tell application \"System Events\" to tell application process \"Adobe InDesign CS6\" to set position of window 1 to {1000, 400}") & " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Customize the delay as needed.  This will be a magical value you that will have to figure out.  Depending your needs, you might be able to put in a test to see if the dialog has disappeared before the script continues.

The bit at the end, `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`, tells bash to redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` (junk it) and redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, then tells the whole command to run in the background.  Without this entire chunk, this statement will block AppleScript from continuing until the shell script finishes executing.

Comment: Welp, this worked, but the delay is there even if I set the delay to zero. This is probably as good as it will get, though. Thanks!